# MongoDB Need to $push array in nested foreach loops

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections:  parents, children and links with subset of data like:

Parents:

```
{ "_id": 1, "PID" : 1, "Pname" : "Joe", "Sal" : 20000 },
{ "_id": 2, "PID" : 2, "Pname" : "Jim", "Sal" : 14100 },
{ "_id": 3, "PID" : 3, "Pname" : "Bob", "Sal" : 13500 },
{ "_id": 4, "PID" : 4, "Pname" : "Amy", "Sal" : 12000 },
{ "_id": 5, "PID" : 5, "Pname" : "George", "Sal" : 10000 }
```

Children:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "CID" : 1, "Cname" : "Ronney", "Age" : 10 },
{ "_id" : 2, "CID" : 2, "Cname" : "Mo", "Age" : 11 },,
{ "_id" : 3, "CID" : 3, "Cname" : "Adam", "Age" : 13 },
{ "_id" : 4, "CID" : 4, "Cname" : "Eve", "Age" : 21 },
{ "_id" : 5, "CID" : 5, "Cname" : "Johny", "Age" : 19 },
{ "_id" : 6, "CID" : 6, "Cname" : "Sammy", "Age" : 25 },
{ "_id" : 7, "CID" : 7, "Cname" : "Sammy", "Age" : 23 }
```

Links:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "PID" : 1, "CID" : 1 },
{ "_id" : 2, "PID" : 1, "CID" : 3 },
{ "_id" : 3, "PID" : 2, "CID" : 5 },
{ "_id" : 4, "PID" : 2, "CID" : 7 },
{ "_id" : 5, "PID" : 2, "CID" : 2 },
{ "_id" : 6, "PID" : 4, "CID" : 4 },
{ "_id" : 7, "PID" : 5, "CID" : 6 }
```

I need to $push an array of children names into to the parents collection using the links collections which tie parent id to child id. So, for example Parent 1 will have:

```
{ "_id" :1, "PID" : 1, "Pname" : "Joe", "Sal" : 20000, “Children” : [“Ronny”, ”Adam”]} }
```

I think I can use a nested foreach loops to achieve this, but I am confused about how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very relational design. Is this coming from a RDBMS migration or are you starting fresh? Have you looked at [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) at all, as a way to source the structure without needing to run `.find()` queries in a loop?

Comment: the data came from 3 .csv files. I am not familiar with $lookup at all...

Comment: Which version of MongoDB is being used? User `db.version()` in a shell if not sure. If you have at least `3.2` then we can simply the process using `$lookup`. Also the point here is to "update" the data so the "Parents" objects will permanently keep an array of "children names"? Or do you just want to "display" the results with the list of children names, and leave the data as is?

Comment: version 3.4.3.  I need to update the parents collection to permanently keep the array of children names.    How would I use $lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forego the usage of "nested loops" with any MongoDB version supporting the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operation. This will allow the "joining" of the data from multiple sources into **one** result set.

Given the collections "parents", "children" and "links", you want to perform two [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operations followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) statements to get the related data from "links" first and then join that to the "children".

Finally for convenience you can [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get the child names into an array for each parent:

```
db.parents.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "links",
    "localField": "PID",
    "foreignField": "PID",
    "as": "children"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$children" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "localField": "children.CID",
    "foreignField": "CID",
    "as": "children"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$children" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "children": { "$push": "$children.Cname" }
  }}
])
```

Which on your data sample gives output like:

```
{ "_id" : 4, "children" : [ "Eve" ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "children" : [ "Sammy" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "children" : [ "Johny", "Sammy", "Mo" ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "children" : [ "Ronney", "Adam" ] }
```

Now you want to use that data output as a basis to loop and update the appropriate "parent" documents. Taking into consideration that the actual data can and will likely be much larger:

```
let ops = [];

db.parents.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "links",
    "localField": "PID",
    "foreignField": "PID",
    "as": "children"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$children" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "localField": "children.CID",
    "foreignField": "CID",
    "as": "children"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$children" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "children": { "$push": "$children.Cname" }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  ops = [
    ...ops,
    {
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
        "update": {
          "$push": { "Children": { "$each": doc.children } }
        }
      }
    }
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.parents.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length != 0 ) { 
  db.parents.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Which then ammends your data as :

```
{ "_id" : 1, "PID" : 1, "Pname" : "Joe", "Sal" : 20000, "Children" : [ "Ronney", "Adam" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "PID" : 2, "Pname" : "Jim", "Sal" : 14100, "Children" : [ "Johny", "Sammy", "Mo" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "PID" : 3, "Pname" : "Bob", "Sal" : 13500 }
{ "_id" : 4, "PID" : 4, "Pname" : "Amy", "Sal" : 12000, "Children" : [ "Eve" ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "PID" : 5, "Pname" : "George", "Sal" : 10000, "Children" : [ "Sammy" ] }
```

The alternate to using the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator would be to use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) instead to write the whole array at once. But it is generally safter to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) which accounts for the "possibility" that an array may already exist at the location, and the intent is to "add" rather than "overwrite.

Comment: this works perfectly.  Much more elaborate than I was expecting.  Thanks.  what would be the easiest way to query the update parents collection to get the parent name and the number of children.  I know I can undwind the array and group by numchildren: {sum:1}, but how do I get parent "Bob" to show with 0 children?  thanks